# products of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I encountered this statement: $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ , then $\mathbb{Z_{m} \times Z_{n}}$ is cyclic of order $mn$.

I just want to know if this works in this case:

(1) if $\gcd(m,n) \neq 1$ , then $\mathbb{Z_{m} \times Z_{n}}$ is not cyclic and its order is not $mn$

or

(2) if $\gcd(m,n) \neq 1$ , then $\mathbb{Z_{m} \times Z_{n}}$ is cyclic but not of order $mn$.

I think its the first one because I'm looking at the example $\mathbb{Z_{2}\times Z_{4}}$ and the $\gcd(4,2)=2$ and it is not cyclic and the order is not $8$.

Am I right?

Comment: Not really: $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is indeed not cyclic, but its order is $mn$ since the factors have order $m$ and $n$  respectively.

Comment: Interesting, are there other cases?

Comment: Well, it is a particular case of the *Structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups*, which is extended to a *Structure theorem for finitely generated for modules over a PID*. You can have more information on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain).